# Android Studio how to implement anchor links in a LinearLayout element?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a page, it consists of several TextViews inside the LinearLayout tag. How to make a link when you click on which the screen scrolls to a specific TextView. For example, the first link will scroll the screen to @ string / faq01, the second to @ string / faq02, etc.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:text="@string/links"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:text="@string/faq01"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:text="@string/faq02"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:text="@string/faq02"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do programmatically using requestFocus function. Give Id to each of yoyr TextView and in your code. When ever user click the Text, requestFocus for the next TextView. See the example Kotlin code:

```
var link:TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_firstLink)
link.setOnClickListener({
       faq1.requestFocus()
    }))
```